# Copy SQL Server Express table to SQL Server CE table for vs2012

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and trying to import or copy a table from a SQL Server 2008 Express database to a local db using SQL Server Compact Edition for VS2012.

I have found there be no management support in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 / 20008 for Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server CE local DB.

They only management interface I can use is Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition.. which I can access both Db's with.

But when I try to copy the table into VS2012 using the following SQL from the CE SQL new query command..

```
 INSERT INTO sqlcedbname.dbo.testdata     
 SELECT * from sql2008dbname.dbo.testdata     (both tables are the same name)
```

It will not give me any data -- and acts like it can't find the database name it just ignores them and thinks I want to copy from my ce table 'cetable' into my 'cetable'

Both tables in SQL Server 2008 R2 and VS2012 CE are the exact structure and name.. but the CE table does not have any data in it.

Also it -- (VS2012 CE Support) -- does not read from a sql script file created in 2008 SSMS successfully either.

Comment: Use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in, allows you to script a single Server table w data

Comment: @ErikEJ -- can you explain? Does that add-in to the VS2012 IDE allow a sql ce table to read a 2008 sql script?    I don't understand how you mean script a single server table w data.

Comment: add 'linq-to-sql' tag.. current vs2012 app is connected web.config to the sql 2008 db populated with data -- looking for input on moving that data to CE local db seems like it should be easy?   Nonetheless, expect LINQ to be a possibility but I have not used Linq yet.. will try.

Comment: Try the addin. You can script a Server table, and then run that script against a SQL CE database, all within the addin.

Comment: @ErikEJ -- GREAT!!  it took me a while to right click and add the sql server scripting to the CE window.. but alas, I persisted.. thank you for the great tool..!!

Answer (score 0):

Use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in, allows you to script a single Server table w data - right click the "root" tree node to connect and export data from a SQL Server database.